# Grid not working. <Col span={12}></Col> Not Working

Tags: grid, row, antd, col

I'm trying to code the most basic grid.

1 Row, 2 Columns.  I can't get it to create 2 columns...

Here's my code:

```
    <Row>
      <Col span={12}>Col 1</Col>
      <Col span={12}>Col 2</Col>
    </Row>
```

[Here's how it's displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJiCs.png)

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written is correct. Make sure that you have imported Antd CSS (import 'antd/dist/antd.css')

```
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';

const Demo = () => {
  return (
  <>
   <Row>
     <Col span={12}>Col 1</Col>
     <Col span={12}>Col 2</Col>
   </Row>
 </>
);
}
export default Demo;
```